# PHP - Compare urls - is shown page the same

Tags: php, header, compare

These two links:
signals.network/join/47AA4E
signals.network/join/

Gives me practically the same page. The last part of the link is a parameter the page uses to identify the referrer

I am creating a page where users submits ref-links
And I need to recognize if the page has already been submitted
So the input url that I receive will be the long version
And I need to test if the short version compares to the long

In this case:
 
westart.co/project/nuggets-airdrop
westart.co/project/
They do not return same result

It does not need to be idiot proof - but I would like to remove the majority of duplicate page submissions

Comment: seems like it would be very problematic, how do you know  ahead of time that `signals.network/join` is `signals.network/join/something`  it could be for example `signals.network/user` and `signals.network/user/login` one is a profile page,the other a login form...  In other words completely different.

Comment: That said, do you mean to strip of the last `/something`?  What have you tried PHP wise.  I would suggest using `explode('/', $url)`, and then `array_slice` to chop it down to size.

Comment: I do not know if they are the same - that's the challenge. However, I've seen enough examples to know that this is common practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to strip part of URI after last `'/'` you can use this expression:

```
substr($REQUEST_URI, 0, strrpos($REQUEST_URI, '/'))
```

then you can compare to base one:

```
$REQUEST_URI = 'westart.co/project/nuggets-airdrop';
$base_uri = 'westart.co/project';

$test = substr($REQUEST_URI, 0, strrpos($REQUEST_URI, '/')) == $base_uri;
print "identical? ".$test;
```

Please note that this expression trims also last occurrence of `'/'`, watch out for it during comparison.

If you need more generic approach and are familiar with composer (or want to dive into PHP world) try to use [URI library](https://uri.thephpleague.com/), then you can do the same expression on `path` key.